# What does : => A syntax mean in method parameter declaration?

Tags: scala, function-parameter, pass-by-name

So, reading the [Scala tour about implicit](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) classes in Scala, I came across this piece of code:

```scala
object Helpers {
  implicit class IntWithTimes(x: Int) {
    def times[A](f: => A): Unit = {
      def loop(current: Int): Unit =
        if(current > 0) {
          f
          loop(current - 1)
        }
      loop(x)
    }
  }
}
```

What is troubling me here is the `def times[A](f: => A): Unit = {` line. What is going on here?
The part of the function type parameter, `A`, I understand, but I cannot fully comprehend out what is the `(f: => A)` part. 
Is it denoting that f is a function which takes any kind / number of arguments, and return an object of type A?

Therefore, does this construction effectively mean a function which takes whatever parameters and return whatever I want?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Please, please, please, put answers in answers, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a chat on the topic from Scala gitter [channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=5e542fe4ed27b13c42f9dee3) providing an excelent analogy for **by-name** parameters

> *Gavin Bisesi @Daenyth Feb 24 17:08*
>
> `=> X` is "by-name" syntax It's syntax sugar for something that's very much like `() => X` The caller doesn't need to supply the `() =>` part,
>   and referencing it in the method body also doesn't need `()` but
>   otherwise is basically the same
>
> *Rob Norris @tpolecat Feb 24 17:17*
>
> ...I think it's best to think of by-name arguments acting like `def`s and
>   normal arguments acting like `val`s. Under the covers it's a nullary
>   function but from the language's point of view it's different. `def foo(a: => String)` and `def foo(a: () => String)` have different types
>   and a behaves differently in the body of each foo.
>
> *Fabio Labella @SystemFw Feb 24 20:19*
>
> @Daenyth re `def/val` `:A /: => A` I actually start my tutorials on
>   programs as values with that. `def/: => A` is related to "being", vs
>   `val/: A` is related to "doing", and understanding the doing/being
>   dichotomy is really useful to understanding FP with effects, and it
>   also translates to pure FP paradigms that actually use native "doing"
>   (unlike as what we do with programs as values, where everything is
>   "being" and "doing" happens in a metalanguage of combinators such as
>   `flatMap`). An example would be algebraic effects in Unison