# How should i understand this definition "final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: (A) => B): B"

Tags: scala, fold, pass-by-name

i knew this question might be dumb.

I just found myself have difficulty understanding the `fold` definition from `Scala Option`[link](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#fold[B](ifEmpty:=%3EB)(f:A=%3EB):B).

Can anyone help me to understand the definition part? `final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: (A) => B): B`

What does `(ifEmpty: => B)` mean, does the `ifEmpty` here represents a function? What does the right part `=> B` represent? Does it represent a function without any parameter? Should that be `() => B`?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but before they close this question let me answer it. `=> B` is a [**by name parameter**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html), which basically means the same as `() => B` but has some syntactic and semantic differences. It is also known as lazy parameters because it is only evaluated if used. In this case, it makes sense. The idea of `fold` on option is to be a shortcut of `opt.map(f).getOrElse(default) === opt.fold(ifEmpty = default)(f)` So, if you have a value you map it, if not you give the value to return, which is not always necessary, thus lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quite a lot of going on in definition of

```
final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: (A) => B): B
```

We have

- [by-name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440684/5205022) parameter `ifEmpty: => B`. This is indeed similar to `() => B` and means `ifEmpty` is not evaluated until used (if ever) inside the method body.
- multiple parameter lists `(ifEmpty: => B)(f: (A) => B)` which [helps type inference](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html#drive-type-inference) because Scala type inference works per list. This means we do not have to explicitly provide `[B]` type parameter at call-site.
- type parameters `A` and `B` make the method polymorphic
- `final` prevents the method from being overriden
- `fold` is a higher-order method because it accepts argument of function type `(A) => B`